# Using LINQ, get a list of objects that contain a particular property value

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have two simple models:

```
 public class Product()
        {
           public long CategoryId {get; set;}
           //...etc
        }

 public class ProductCategory()
        {
           public long Id {get; set;}
           //...etc
        }
```

I've written a query to store a list of ProductCategory.Id numbers.

```
List<long> activeProductCategories
```

Now I would like to write a Linq Query that gets a List of all of the Products that have CategoryId equal to any long in activeProductCategories.

I have started writing something like the following, but have yet to make much progress:

```
List<Product> activeProducts = UnitOfWork.ProductRepository.Get().Where(a=>a.CategoryId //... ?
```

Comment: `.Where(a => activeProductCategories.Contains(a.CategoryId);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a linq `Contains()` method

```
List<Product> activeProducts = UnitOfWork.ProductRepository.Get()
    .Where(a => activeProductCategories.Contains(a.CategoryId)).ToList();
```